# Rails 3: jquery to change partials

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

rails newbie herem, I'm looking to learn a little bit about jquery so I figured I'd try to switch between my partial views using AJAX.

Right now on my user's dash I have a link to their 'likes' page, it requires a full reload to see the 'likes' page, how would I change this to refresh  with the likes_user_path@user)??

views/pages/home.html.erb

```
  <div id="left">
    <div id="dash-statistics">
       <a href="<%= likes_user_path(@user) %>">
         <div id="likes" class="stat">Likes
           <%= @user.likes.count %>
         </div>
       </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="right">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
  </div>
```

UsersController

```
  def likes
    @title = "Likes"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @like_stuff = @user.likes.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    render 'show_likes' 
  end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to reload the `likes` by clicking a link, by using ajax, in your user dashboard.

First thing to do is rewrite the link, and add a `:remote => true` like this:

```
<%= link_to "Likes", likes_user_path(@user), :remote => true %>
```

Then, in your controller, make sure you have a `respond_to :html, :js` at the top (there can of course be other options, but `:js` has to be among them)

After that, you could do a function called `likes` in your controller which to use for loading the likes, which looks something like yours, only you don't do `render` at the end, but `respond_with @likes`. By having `:js` in the `respond_to` filter, Rails will automagically act accordingly when supposed to.

Next, make a corresponding view called `likes.js.erb` (i'm not exactly sure if coffeescript will work out of the box in this case) in which you put something like

```
$('#likes').html('<%= escape_javascript(render "likes", :likes => @likes) %>');
```

This assumes that in your main view in which you want to render the likes ,there's an element with the `id=likes` which could look like this:

```
<div id="likes">
  <%= render "likes", :likes => @likes %>
</div>
```

and there's also a `_likes.html.erb` partial which renders the likes

```
<% likes.each do |like| %>
  <div>
    <%= like.name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And with this I think I pretty much covered it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Maybe I'm still to new at rails to understand this, or perhaps its just jquery that I'm not understanding. Which controller and method would the respond_to :html, :js go in exactly?  How would the respond_with @Likes work? I don't follow that at all. I need the likes page to render inside the div id="content". Still confused as how this works. Sorry if I'm new.

Comment: To be specific, in your case, the controller is Users, and in your question there's an action called `likes` that should return the likes accordingly (that function is pretty much ok, although I would refactor the likes and put them in the `User` model, but that's another story; anyway, the `likes` action must end with `respond_with`, and not `render`, you're calling it using ajax, then Rails will render the `likes` partial inside your `#likes` div - check out `likes.js.erb` - it replaces the content of the html inside `#likes`)