# Unable to bind ajax:success to form created with form_for .... :remote => true

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, form-for

I'm using Rails 3.1.1

I have the following in a haml view:

```
= form_for booking.notes.build, :remote => true do |f|
  = f.text_area(:content)
  = f.hidden_field(:noteable_id)
  = f.hidden_field(:noteable_type)
  = f.submit('Add note')
```

Which creates new notes on submission. Also the response from my controller is appearing correctly in a Chrome console (Network tab). But I cannot seem to grab the response.

I want to update the note list on the page after submission. I've been trying to bind to the ajax response so I can grab the response, but I am failing. For example, I think this should work but does not:

```
$('#new_note').bind('ajax:success', function() {
  alert('Hi');
});
```

But no alert is triggered. Which I think explains why this also doesn't work.

```
 $('#new_note').bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
  // Insert response partial into page below the form.
  $(this).parent.append(xhr.responseText);

})
```

Can you please point me as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: I've got around this by using a create.js.erb with code that updates the necessary object. But I'd rather be able to grab the ajax call, so that I can use the ajax error object if necessary.

Answer (score 9):

Did you try 'ajax:complete'?

Other things that can go wrong here:

Status code was not really "successful". This triggers success in jQuery

```
if ( status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304 ) {
```

Or the event handler was evaluated before the form was rendered. Try event delegation:

```
$("body").on('ajax:success', '#new_note', function(){...})
```

(careful, this is the new jQuery syntax. If using old jQuery, adjust accordingly)

Comment: As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxSuccess() method should only be attached to document.

Comment: This is not ajaxSuccess(). Rails still triggers 'ajax:success' event on the element with data-remote='true'.

Comment: This is that "UJS" stuff, right? Sorry! Your answer is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

if you want, you can put your javascript in create.js.erb (code in this file will be executed after response will come to your browser)
And in this file you can use if statement, like

```
<% if @ok %>
  //your code
<% end %>
```

if in your controller's action set @ok to false the response will be empty!

Answer (score 0):

This is generally done by doing a `create.js.erb` file in your controller's view section (if haven't done so already) in which you have access to whatever variables come out of the create action, and there you can render your html

in your `create.js.erb` file you could write something like

```
$("#new_note").html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "path/to/partial") %>');
```

read more in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865198/rails-3-jquery-to-change-partials/7865923#7865923) I wrote some time ago, it pretty much explains the whole flow

Comment: It is debatable that this is "generally done". I personally consider it a bad practice that makes your code less maintainable. JS should go to your assets folder where it belongs.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the assets, it's how javascript handlers are handled by default in Rails

Comment: All I'm saying is - just because you can return javascript from the controller - doesn't mean it's the best solution. Matter of taste I guess and I don't like this approach.